# Add O365 licences via powershell csv import?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I have a script I use to create new users and would like to also add a few more lines into it so as for it to append an O365 license to each new user created (free licences already existing in O365), and then give one user access over each of these users' calendars and inboxes.

My working code so far is:

```
        Import-Csv "C:\blablabla\filename.csv" | ForEach-Object { 
    New-ADUser -Name $_.Name `
     -GivenName $_."GivenName" `
     -Surname $_."Surname" `
     -DisplayName $_."DisplayName" `
     -SamAccountName  $_."samAccountName" `
     -UserPrincipalName  $_."UserPrincipalName" `
     -Path $_."Path" `
     -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “Pa$$w0rd” -AsPlainText -force) -Enabled $true `
     -EmailAddress $_."EmailAddress" `
     -ProfilePath $_."ProfilePath" `
     -HomeDrive $_."HomeDrive" `
     -HomeDirectory $_."HomeDirectory" `
     -ScriptPath $_."ScriptPath" `
     -Server $_."Server" `
    }
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
```

The other lines I have to add are

```
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName "@domain.com" -AddLicenses "domain:STANDARDPACK" 
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity newuser@domain.com -User 'admin@domain.com' -AccessRight FullAccess -InheritanceType All -Automapping $false 
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity newuser@domain.com:\calendar -user admin@domain.com -AccessRights Editor
```

My problem is I don't know how to add these last three commands into the script above so that these three actions would be done for each user that gets created from the csv and so that the UPNs would be pulled from the csv.

I already have a working script to connect to O365 with saved credentials before these three lines, which is:

```
$AdminName = "admin@domain.com"
$Pass = Get-Content "C:\blablabla\O365Credentials.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $Pass
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```

I guess I could just add this "connect to O365" bit in between the two, or at the beginning of the script, but, I just don't know how to merge those three commands with the rest of the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

(does anyone else know how to do this then?)

Comment: I'm not to keen on trying to do this in one script myself, because between the creation of the new users in AD and setting an Office365 license you need to first ensure the servers are synchronized and mailboxes are created. This can take up some time..

Comment: Well, I do have a force policy sync line at the end, I forgot to add that in the script, basically it does an adsync policy initial after it creates users and they do get created and synced immediately. Any thoughts? (I've added that to the post now)

Comment: Yes, that's fine and all, but the creation of mailboxes can take up a considerable amount time.. I would hate to add a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 900` or so to halt the script for such a long time. Also, to make sure the `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle` actually runs to completion, I'd advise adding something like this right after the command: `if (Get-ADSyncConnectorRunStatus) { Write-Warning "A sync is already in progress. Please try again later." }; else { While(Get-ADSyncConnectorRunStatus) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 } }; Write-Host "Azure AD Sync has finished."`

Comment: @Theo Yes, I was thinking of adding a pause, indeed, syncing is usually instant but mailbox creation can take a while... 
I guess pausing is my only option, but my issue is I don't know how to merge the three other commands above into one script?

Thanks.

Comment: You could refer to this link: https://joshheffner.com/bulk-assign-licenses-in-office-365-using-powershell/

Comment: @Theo, did you delete your comment from here? I can't see it any more.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the answer, because I have no idea what you are actually doing with the code. Also, you are not showing anything of your 'C:\blablabla\filename.csv' where all the data for the new users should be in. All you comment back is _the script does not even start_, but you should get error messages at the very least if something is wrong, so I really have doubts..

Comment: @Theo. The blablabla is just a link to a csv on the desktop, there is nothing wrong with that. And yes, that is what happens, I copy paste your script, make small modifications to point it to where my csv is, save it as a ps1 and then when I try to run it inside an elevated ISE, absolutely nothing happens. No errors, nothing gets created, absolutely nothing. 

Again, have you tried your script, does it work for you?

If I try my script as above, it works, but yours just doesn't do anything, not even an error. The path to the csv on the desktop is the same for both.

Comment: does anyone else know how to do this then?